# Python function evaluation issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok, I am new to programming and I'm making a python text game for a project in my computer science class.I need to call a function within another function. The only issue I'm having is that the inner function needs to be a parameter within the first so that I can change what function is being called.Here is the block of code that is the offender:

```
`def choosePath(a,b,c,d):
    path = ""
    path = input("Type "+a+" to "+a+" Type "+b+" to "+b+":")
    if path == a:
      c
    elif path == b:
      d
    elif path != a and path != b:
  choosePath(a,b,c,d)`
```

I need c and d to be function calls. I tried this with a print() statement but the print runs before anything else.

Comment: `c()` & `d()`... does that not work? Pass the function by name (without the parenthesis) and call it with them.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `c` and `d` ?

Comment: When you call a function you need the parenthesis as @TemporalWolf said. Can you post the code for `c()` and `d()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parentheses after the function calls.

```
def c():
    print('Calling function `c`')


def d():
    print('Calling function `d`')


def choosePath(a,b,c,d):
    path = ""
    path = input("Type "+a+" to "+a+" Type "+b+" to "+b+":")
    if path == a:
      c()
    elif path == b:
      d()
    elif path != a and path != b:
      choosePath(a,b,c,d)
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved my issue it worked exactly like I thought it should after adding the parentheses.TY for the help.